# .htaccess doesn't work with $_GET

Tags: .htaccess

I have a line in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

and a line in index.php:

```
$page = $_GET['page']; echo $page;
```

If I go to http://www.example.com/test-page, it returns index.php.

The only way to fix it that I've found is to do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

If I go to http://www.example.com/test-page/ it works and outputs test-page.

However, I don't want the webpage to use http://www.example.com/test-page/, I want it to use http://www.example.com/test-page.

How can I fix this, preferably without adding a rule that adds a / to the end of the url in an internal rewrite...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

or try something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This will redirect all traffic to the index.php. You can use e. g. `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` to get your path.

Comment: Lots of webpages use similar code. Could it be because I need to enable an Apache mod? I have mod_rewrite on.

Comment: If your code above works, then mod_rewrite should be available.

Comment: Well, thanks for the update. But later I want to add stuff like

Comment: Why do you need the NC flag? With only [L], isn't it doing what you want?

Comment: RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)/(.*)$ shop.php?page=$1&product=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: @Oliver Yes, mod_rewrite works, I use it above. (Commenting it out doesn't fix my problem) But I just thought something else was special in this case. I don't know :(

Comment: sometimes it depends on your configuration if you need slashes before index.php or ^/(.*)$ but you do not have to add additional plugins. If this does not work, I have no idea.

Comment: @Oliver I figured it out. ^(.*)$ did not work. However, ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ did work. How come?

Comment: Yes, I did. I thought . was any character, just as defining every ASCII-character inside [].